# Adding a dependency between several tasks

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a bunch of 'collectors' enumerating several data from various devices (cpu-type, ram etc.).
These collectors run once a day and post their data using a simple webservice.
This webservice then fires some methods to import this data to our sql-db using EF.

Here's the part after getting the data:

```
 var importPayload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(payload.ToString(),
            new JsonSerializerSettings {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto});

        //Load off the payload to another thread to quickly return to the caller.            
        TypeSwitch.On(importPayload)
            .Case((List<IDeviceType> x) =>
            {
                Task.Run(() => { DeviceType.Update(x, sourceName, sourceId, persistInDatabase); });
            })                
            .Case((List<ICpu> x) =>
            {
                Task.Run(() => { Cpu.Update(x, sourceName, sourceId, persistInDatabase); });
            })
            .Case((List<IMemory> x) =>
            {
                Task.Run(() => { Memory.Update(x, sourceName, sourceId, persistInDatabase); });
            })
```

Here's the part of updating the data in our sql-db.

**1. Device-Type:**

```
public static class DeviceType
{
    private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static readonly DateTime Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    internal static void Update(IReadOnlyCollection<IDeviceType> payload, string sourceName, int sourceId,
        bool persistInDatabase)
    {
        if (payload == null || !payload.Any())
        {
            Log.Error($"Collector '{sourceName}': Payload is 'NULL' or empty. Cannot import payload into CMDB.");
            return;
        }

        using (var context = CMDBEntities.GetCMDBContext(persistInDatabase, sourceName))
        {
            foreach (var item in payload.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name)))
                Update(context, item.HostName, item.Name, sourceId, sourceName);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void Update(CMDBEntities context, string hostName, string systemType, int sourceId,
        string sourceName)
    {
        Log.Debug($"Collector '{sourceName}', Item '{hostName}': Lookup item in CMDB...");

        var ci = context.CMDB_ci.FirstOrDefault(
            a => a.name.ToLower().Equals(hostName.ToLower()) &&
                 a.ci_c_status_id == CiStatus.Active && a.delflag == 0);

        if (ci == null)
        {
            Log.Debug($"Collector '{sourceName}', Item '{hostName}': Item was not found in CMDB. Skipping...");
            return;
        }

        var deviceType =
            context.CMDB_ci_c_devicetype.FirstOrDefault(
                a => a.name.ToLower().Equals(systemType.ToLower()));

        if (deviceType != null)
        {
            var sourceDeviceTypeId = deviceType.ci_c_devicetype_id;
            var cmdbDeviceType = ci.CMDB_ci_devicetype ??
                                 (ci.CMDB_ci_devicetype = new CMDB_ci_devicetype());

            var cmdbDeviceTypeId = ci.CMDB_ci_devicetype.ci_c_devicetype_id;

            if (cmdbDeviceTypeId != sourceDeviceTypeId)
            {
                cmdbDeviceType.ci_c_devicetype_id = sourceDeviceTypeId;
                cmdbDeviceType.LastModBy = sourceName;
                cmdbDeviceType.LastModDateTime = Timestamp;

                ci.LastModBy = sourceName;
                ci.LastModDateTime = Timestamp;
                Log.Debug(
                    $"Collector '{sourceName}', CI '{ci.name}': Device-Type has changed.");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**2. CPU:**

```
 public static class Cpu
 {
     private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
     private static readonly DateTime Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

     internal static void Update(IReadOnlyCollection<ICpu> payload, string sourceName, int sourceId,
        bool persistInDatabase)
    {
        if (payload == null || !payload.Any())
        {
            Log.Error($"Collector '{sourceName}': Payload is 'NULL' or empty. Cannot import payload into CMDB.");
            return;
        }

        using (var context = CMDBEntities.GetCMDBContext(persistInDatabase, sourceName))
        {
            foreach (var item in payload)
                Update(context, item.HostName, item.Name, item.SpeedInMhz, item.Count, item.Cores, sourceId,
                    sourceName);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void Update(CMDBEntities context, string itemName, string cpuName, int? cpuSpeed,
        int? cpuCount,
        int? cpuCoresPerCpu, int dataSourceId, string sourceName)
    {
        Log.Debug($"Collector '{sourceName}', Item '{itemName}': Lookup item in CMDB...");

        var ci = context.CMDB_ci.FirstOrDefault(
            a => a.name.ToLower().Equals(itemName.ToLower()) &&
                 a.ci_c_status_id == CiStatus.Active && a.delflag == 0 &&
                 (a.ci_c_type_id == CiType.Server || a.ci_c_type_id == CiType.Workstation));

        if (ci == null)
        {
            Log.Debug($"Collector '{sourceName}', Item '{itemName}': Item was not found in CMDB. Skipping...");
            return;
        }

        var deviceType = ci.CMDB_ci_devicetype ??
                             (ci.CMDB_ci_devicetype = new CMDB_ci_devicetype{LastModBy = sourceName, LastModDateTime = Timestamp});

        InsertOrUpdateCpuEntry(context, deviceType, ci, cpuName, cpuSpeed, cpuCount, cpuCoresPerCpu,
            sourceName);
    }

    private static void InsertOrUpdateCpuEntry(CMDBEntities context, CMDB_ci_devicetype deviceType, CMDB_ci ci,
        string cpuName, int? cpuSpeed, int? cpuCount, int? cpuCoresPerCpu, string lastModBy)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpuName))
        {
            var cpu = GetOrCreateCpuTypeEntry(context, ci, cpuName, lastModBy);
            deviceType.ci_c_hardware_cpu_id = cpu.ci_c_hardware_cpu_id;
        }

        if (cpuCount != null)
            deviceType.cpuCount = cpuCount;

        if (cpuCoresPerCpu != null)
            deviceType.cpuCoresPerCpu = cpuCoresPerCpu;

        if (cpuSpeed != null)
            deviceType.cpuSpeed = cpuSpeed;
    }

    private static CMDB_ci_c_hardware_cpu GetOrCreateCpuTypeEntry(CMDBEntities context, CMDB_ci ci,
        string cpuName,
        string sourceName)
    {
        var cpu =
            context.CMDB_ci_c_hardware_cpu.FirstOrDefault(
                a => a.value.ToLower().Equals(cpuName.ToLower()));

        if (cpu != null) return cpu;

        //Create new entry using it's own context.
        using (var cpuContext = CMDBEntities.GetCMDBContext())
        {
            if (ci.ci_c_type_id != null)
            {
                var newCpu = cpuContext.CMDB_ci_c_hardware_cpu.Add(new CMDB_ci_c_hardware_cpu
                {
                    ci_c_type_id = (CiType) ci.ci_c_type_id,
                    value = cpuName,
                    alias = cpuName,
                    delflag = 0,
                    deprecated = false,
                    LastModBy = sourceName,
                    LastModDateTime = Timestamp
                });

                Log.Debug($"Collector '{sourceName}': Creating new CPU-Entry: '{0}'", cpuName);
                cpuContext.SaveChanges();

                return newCpu;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
 }
```

**3. RAM:**

```
 public static class Memory
 {
    private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static readonly DateTime Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    internal static void Update(IReadOnlyCollection<IMemory> payload, string sourceName, int sourceId,
        bool persistInDatabase)
    {
        if (payload == null || !payload.Any())
        {
            Log.Error($"Collector '{sourceName}': Payload is 'NULL' or empty. Cannot import payload into CMDB.");
            return;
        }

        using (var context = CMDBEntities.GetCMDBContext(persistInDatabase, sourceName))
        {
            foreach (var item in payload)
                Update(context, item.HostName, item.SizeInGb, sourceId, sourceName);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private static void Update(CMDBEntities context, string itemName, long? ramSizeInGb, int dataSourceId,
        string sourceName)
    {
        Log.Debug($"Collector '{sourceName}', Item '{itemName}': Lookup item in CMDB...");

        var ci = context.CMDB_ci.FirstOrDefault(
            a => a.name.ToLower().Equals(itemName.ToLower()) &&
                 a.ci_c_status_id == CiStatus.Active && a.delflag == 0 &&
                 (a.ci_c_type_id == CiType.Server || a.ci_c_type_id == CiType.Workstation));

        if (ci == null)
        {
            Log.Debug($"Collector '{sourceName}', Item '{itemName}': Item was not found in CMDB. Skipping...");
            return;
        }

        var deviceType = ci.CMDB_ci_devicetype ??
                             (ci.CMDB_ci_devicetype = new CMDB_ci_devicetype{LastModBy = sourceName, LastModDateTime = Timestamp}); 

        InsertOrUpdateRamSizeEntry(deviceType, ramSizeInGb);
    }

    private static void InsertOrUpdateRamSizeEntry(CMDB_ci_devicetype deviceType, long? ramSize)
    {
        deviceType.ramSize = ramSize;
    }
 }
```

In some rare cases, these methods try to insert a new device-type-entry simultaneosly so the EF crashes with a nice error-message:

> 2018-02-01 03:54:12.1435|[Error]|[CMDB.Core.CMDBEntities.SaveChanges] >>> Source 'CMDB-Collector Discovery (Hardware (CPU))': General error while committing changes to database.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Int32 SaveChanges()
>   UpdateException An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Int32 Update()
>   SqlException Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_CMDB_ci_devicetype'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CMDB_ci_devicetype'. The duplicate key value is (414002).

I know the cause of this but I don't know what would be the best way to avoid this error. I could save the changes back after each modification but that would increase the processing-time a lot.
Or I could add some dependencies on the different tasks so that the webservices checks which update-methods are currently running and queues the next one.

Thanks!

Update Table-specs:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CMDB_ci_devicetype](
[ci_devicetype_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ci_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[ci_c_devicetype_id] [bigint] NULL,
[ci_c_hardware_cpu_id] [bigint] NULL,
[cpuCount] [int] NULL,
[cpuCoresPerCpu] [int] NULL,
[cpuSpeed] [int] NULL,
[ramSize] [bigint] NULL,
[cpu_processor_type] [varchar](max) NULL,
[cpu_number_of_sockets] [varchar](max) NULL,
[cpu_populate_sockets] [varchar](max) NULL,
[cpu_core_per_populate_sockets] [varchar](max) NULL,
[cpu_core_per_server] [varchar](max) NULL,
[ram] [varchar](max) NULL,
[controller] [varchar](max) NULL,
[LastModBy] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[LastModDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_CMDB_ci_devicetype] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ci_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Why don't you have identity columns? And please slim down the code to the bare minimum that sufficiently illustrates your issue.

Comment: I do have an identity column?! It's auto-generated by the db. But the problem is, the EF tries to insert the ID of an object (CI) twice. The 'ci_id' is the PK so it won't work. Will update my question with the table specs in a minute.

Comment: The only scenario I can think of where EF will try to insert a duplicate value into an identity column is when EF doesn't know it's an identity column *and* IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. Nothing in your code indicates that's true.